# When is it appropriate to find the limit?

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

Of course you can ask me a question on limits which is an appropriate situation for me to deliver my knowledge of limits.

What I'm really asking is how and when can I apply limits to solve problems that I may encounter in the future? When do I decide "ok, it's time to find the limit."?

Comment: High school physics, for instance?

Comment: @BolzWeir Be specific

Comment: See Newton, Philosophiæ Naturalis Principia Mathematica, for some interesting, and history changing, examples.

Comment: @zhw. I leave those books for smart people like you to translate for me

Comment: @NormalHuman What is funny? The question?

Comment: A simple example is the derivative.
A more complicated example is finding the final state solution for a probability problem, viz. stochastic matrices.

You should take the limit when things get very very small, but not quite zero, or if they get larger and larger without stopping, and you want to decide what would happen if things do that.

An example is asking yourself: If the mass of an object changes according to it's speed via the relativistic formula: $m=\frac{m_0}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$, then what happens to mass when you go very close to the speed of light? This requires limits.

Comment: @nathan.j.mcdougall oh yeah right. I forget about the formal definition of the derivative or something like that

Comment: @user269350 That's a fairly significant thing to forget.

Comment: @nathan.j.mcdougall thank you for the relativistic formula, I like that example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything you learn in calculus *after* limits is uses limits in some way.  Limits are just the foundation.  Do you want to find the slope of a curve at a point?  Use a limiting process called a *derivative*.  Do you want to find area of some complex curvy shape?  Use a limiting process called an *integral*.  Do you want to sum an infinite sequence of numbers?  Use a limiting process called an *infinite series*.  Want to know is some crazy function defined algebraically is continuous?  Use limits.  Everything in calculus is based on limits.

Comment: It's all about the approximation huh

Comment: @user269350, No it's better than that. We get *exact* results for a process that in real life, by taking measurements, would only be an approximation.